# Apache Spark out of Java heap space: where does it happen?

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have a Java memory issue with Spark. The same application working on my 8GB Mac crashes on my 72GB Ubuntu server...

I have changed things in the conf file, but it looks like Spark does not care, so I wonder if my issues are with the driver or executor.

I set:

```
spark.driver.memory             20g
spark.executor.memory           20g
```

And, whatever I do, the crash is always at the same spot in the app, which makes me think that it is a driver problem.

The exception I get is:

```
16/07/13 20:36:30 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 7.0 (TID 208, micha.nc.rr.com): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.nio.HeapCharBuffer.<init>(HeapCharBuffer.java:57)
    at java.nio.CharBuffer.allocate(CharBuffer.java:335)
    at java.nio.charset.CharsetDecoder.decode(CharsetDecoder.java:810)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.Text.decode(Text.java:412)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.Text.decode(Text.java:389)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.Text.toString(Text.java:280)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.JSONRelation$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$json$JSONRelation$$createBaseRdd$1.apply(JSONRelation.scala:105)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.JSONRelation$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$json$JSONRelation$$createBaseRdd$1.apply(JSONRelation.scala:105)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.foldLeft(TraversableOnce.scala:144)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foldLeft(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.aggregate(TraversableOnce.scala:201)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.aggregate(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$treeAggregate$1$$anonfun$23.apply(RDD.scala:1135)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$treeAggregate$1$$anonfun$23.apply(RDD.scala:1135)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$treeAggregate$1$$anonfun$24.apply(RDD.scala:1136)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$treeAggregate$1$$anonfun$24.apply(RDD.scala:1136)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$20.apply(RDD.scala:710)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$20.apply(RDD.scala:710)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:227)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Any hint? Thanks

**Update:**

I have set a small memory "dumper" in my app. At the beginning, it says:

```
**  Free ......... 1,413,566
**  Allocated .... 1,705,984
**  Max .......... 16,495,104
**> Total free ... 16,202,686
```

Just before the crash, it says:

```
**  Free ......... 1,461,633
**  Allocated .... 1,786,880
**  Max .......... 16,495,104
**> Total free ... 16,169,857
```

Comment: what JVM in each machine?

Comment: From the stack trace, this is a crash in the executor.

Comment: @Leo: They all run Java 8, Spark 1.6.2

Comment: @Dikei: This was my conclusion too, but I could not understand why the executor would not take the memory parameter from the configuration file. It worked as I set it up dynamically (see my answer).

Answer (score 0):

So for some reason, I have not been able to make the configuration file read by Spark on the server side, but modifying my code to:

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf()
    .setAppName("app")
    .set("spark.executor.memory", "4g")
    .setMaster("spark://10.0.100.120:7077");
```

(Thanks to all the people who voted the question down, it is really motivating to come back here and post a solution).